# CSS Animation, Reverse not working IE10

Tags: css, animation, internet-explorer-10, reverse

I'm having some trouble with IE10 accepting the reverse direction property on my CSS animation. Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE11 are all ok, but IE10 will accept an animation travelling left to right, but not right to left using reverse.

Here's the code:

```
.city {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0px;
}

.traffic-right {
    @extend .city;
    background-image: url("../images/traffic_right.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    -webkit-animation: animate 35s linear infinite;
            animation: animate 35s linear infinite;
}

.traffic-left {
    @extend .city;
    background-image: url("../images/traffic_left.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    -webkit-animation: animate 35s linear reverse infinite;
            animation: animate 35s linear reverse infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    from {background-position: 0px;}
    to {background-position: 2000px;}
}

@keyframes animate {
    from {background-position: 0px;}
    to {background-position: 2000px;}
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the keyframes instead:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    from {background-position: 0px;}
    to {background-position: -2000px;}
}

@keyframes animate {
    from {background-position: 0px;}
    to {background-position: -2000px;}
}
```

Then take the `reverse` out:

```
-webkit-animation: animate 35s linear infinite;
        animation: animate 35s linear infinite;
```

Comment: Thank you. Although this is not the ideal solution as it adds more code to have an animation going forwards and another going in reverse, it does in fact work.

Comment: @user1597713 just as a test, can you try to use `backwards` instead of `reverse`? See if that works?

Comment: Tried this as you've suggested. This is sending the animation backwards, but backwards upon itself. *difficult to explain*

Comment: If traffic right is meant to go --> and Traffic left uses the same animation but with `reverse` property on it should go <--

However traffic right will go --> and traffic left `backwards` also goes -->

Therefore I have to have traffic right --> as usual, but traffic left with `backwards` && `-2000px` enabled as well to make it go <--

if that makes sense??

Comment: Me too, as I say it works on Safari, Chrome, IE11 and Firefox just fine. It's like it's not a supported property, but I've not been able to find anything to say that it's not. I've tried it as animation-direction: as well.